# How can i change deployed application to webserver from application server?

Tags: java, maven, weblogic-10.x

I am having a web application which is deployed in oracle weblogic application server. After getting analysed, i found that there is no need for application server(atleast for this application), i am in need to deploy this application into the oracle weblogic web server.

can anyone help on this, how can i change deployed application to webserver from application server ?

Or in a different words, i can say how can i migrate my application deployment from oracle weblogic application server to oracle weblogic web server ?

I am using weblogic 10.  and Maven to build the application

About the application, it is using Apache axis, webservices, jsf, and few java classes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recently migrated one application from WAS to tomcat
The approach i followd is.

- Identify and remove all the WL specific dependencies / jars (that you may not need of)
- Change the build script to generate .war instead of .ear
- deploy the generated .war to any servlet container/ webserver

with your specs (axis,ws,jsf) you dont need a .ear but .war will do.

if you are using ant modify your build script, i'd suggest go for maven for better dependency management

Comment: Thanks for quick reply....   It is helping atleast I got how to start doing this.   Thanks again for this

Comment: Now according to C.R. i need to add JMS also which is not posibble with tomcat. I am in need to use JBOSS. Can you please let me know where to change in POM.xml and what to write for JBOSS ?

Comment: Thanks for your very good answer.

Now i need to start JMS service also to the server so I am not able to user Tomcat, I am in need to your JBOSS now.

i was not able to find how to modify my current pom.xml and which tag to modify.

Can you please explain a bit on that also ?

Thanks in advance or that.

Comment: if you like the answer you can acceptit , though your openion is respected

Answer (score 0):

building of top of the answer by @TechExchange

even for Jboss, you still need to analyze the application to remove all WL specifics.
Ex: Descriptors for EJB's MDB's and so on.
with JBOSS you can still use the ear format.

A quesiton, you had mentioned that because you found that the application doesn't need a app server you decided to migrate it to web server, now with JMS in the picture do you still need to move?